# CQRS/Event Sourcing - Does one expect to receive an Aggregate Id from the user/request?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, aggregateroot

I am currently just trying to learn some new programming patterns and I decided to give event sourcing a shot.

I have decided to model a warehouse as my aggregate root in the domain of shipping/inventory where the number of warehouses is generally pretty constant (i.e. a company wont be adding warehouses too often).

I have run into the question of how to set my aggregateId, which should correspond to a warehouse, on my server. Most examples I have seen, including [this one](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r/blob/master/CQRSGui/Controllers/HomeController.cs), show the aggregate ID being generated server side when a new aggregate is being created (in my case a warehouse), and then passed in the command request when referring to that aggregate for subsequent commands.

Would you say this is the correct approach? C*an I expect the user to know and pass aggregate Ids when issuing commands?* I realize this is probably domain dependent and could also be a UI/UX choice as well, just wondering what other's have done. It would make more sense to me if the number of my event sourced aggregates were more frequent, such as with meal tabs or shopping carts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heuristic: aggregate id, in many cases, is analogous to the primary key used to distinguish entities in a database table.  Many of the lessons of *natural* vs *surrogate* keys apply.

> Can I expect the user to know and pass aggregate Ids when issuing commands?

You probably can't depend on the *human* to know the aggregate ids.  But the *client* that the human operator is using can very well know them.

For instance, if an operator is going to be working in a single warehouse during a session, then we might look up the appropriate identifier, cache it, and use it when constructing messages on behalf of the user.

Analog: when you fill in a web form and submit it, the *browser* does the work of looking at the form action and using that information to construct the correct URI, and similarly the correct HTTP Request.

The client will normally know what the ID is, because it just got it during a previous query.

*Creation* patterns are weird.  It can, in some circumstances, make sense for the client to choose the identifier to be used when creating a new aggregate.  In others, it makes sense for the client to provide an identifier for the command message, and the server decides for itself what the aggregate identifier should be.

It's messaging, so you want to be careful about coupling the client directly to your internal implementation details -- especially if that client is under a different development schedule.  If you get the message contract right, then the server and client can evolve in any way consistent with the contract at any time.

You may want to review Greg Young's 10 year retrospective, which includes a discussion of [warehouse systems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDW0QWie21s&t=10m48s).  TL;DR - in many cases the messages coming from the human operators are *events*, not commands.

Comment: Thanks for the video! Very informative. I wish he would have talked a bit more about the warehouse domain though, was just a quick blurb on it. Still helpful though.

Answer (score 1):

> Would you say this is the correct approach?

You're asking if one of Greg Young's Event Sourcing samples represents the correct approach... Given that the combination of CQRS and Event Sourcing was essentially (re)invented by Greg, I'd say there's a pretty good chance of that.

In general, letting the code that implements the Command-side generate a GUID for every Command, Event, or other persistent object that it needs to write is by far the simplest implementation, since GUIDs are guaranteed to be unique. In a distributed system, uniqueness without coordination is a big thing.

> Can I expect the user to know and pass aggregate Ids when issuing commands?

No, and you particularly can't expect a user to know the GUID of their assets. What you may be able to do is to present the user with a list of his or her assets. Each item in the list will have the GUID associated, but it may not be necessary to surface that ID in the user interface. It's just data that the underlying UI object carries around internally.

In some cases, users do need to know the ID of some of their assets (e.g. if it involves phone support). In that case, you can [add a lookup API to address that concern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/08/11/cqs-versus-server-generated-ids).